# How to position one node below another so that shorter one starts where the wider one does (instead of being centered)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, positioning, nodes

I need bottom nodes to start where their respective top nodes instead of being centered below them.

Output:

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left,draw=black,rounded corners](colOne_rowOne)
{
this is line 1\\
this is line 2, this is line 2
};
\node[below=of colOne_rowOne,align=left,draw=black,rounded corners](colOne_rowTwo)
{
this is line
};
\node[right=of colOne_rowOne,align=left,draw=black,rounded corners](colTwo_rowOne)
{
this is line 1\\
this is line 2, this is line 2
};
\node[below=of colTwo_rowOne,align=left,draw=black,rounded corners](colTwo_rowTwo)
{
this is line
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem. So is the problem that you want the smaller boxes left aligned underneath the bigger boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Zarko's answer is working in this case, I think it is cleaner to use anchors for this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={align=left,draw=black,rounded corners}]
    \node[box](colOne_rowOne)
    {
        this is line 1\\
        this is line 2, this is line 2
    };
    \node[box, below=of colOne_rowOne.south west, anchor=north west](colOne_rowTwo)
    {
        this is west-aligned
    };
    \node[box, right=of colOne_rowOne](colTwo_rowOne)
    {
        this is line 1\\
        this is line 2, this is line 2
    };
    \node[box, below=of colTwo_rowOne.south east, anchor=north east](colTwo_rowTwo)
    {
        this is east-aligned
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Anchors are fitted for this task: they tell which point of the current node should be positioned at the given coordinate. Then you can use the `node distance` key to change the distances between the nodes.

[image: rendering]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

it is not fun reconstruct the missing preamble: it contain important information for the image drawings ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 0mm,
box/.style = {shape=rectangle, draw, rounded corners, align=left}
                        ]
\node[box](colOne_rowOne)
        {
        this is line 1\\
        this is line 2, this is line 2
        };
\node[box, below right=of colOne_rowOne.south west](colOne_rowTwo)
        {
        this is line
        };
\node[box, right=6mm of colOne_rowOne](colTwo_rowOne)
        {
        this is line 1\\
        this is line 2, this is line 2
        };
\node[box, below right=of colTwo_rowOne.south west] (colTwo_rowTwo)
        {
        this is line
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```